# Gradle is not looking for custom maven repository

Tags: react-native, maven, gradle

I have a react native library called react-native-expofp and I am trying to add CrowdConnected module there, according to this [docs](https://expofp.github.io/expofp-mobile-sdk/android-sdk/4.2.12.html#crowdconnected-location-provider) I need to add `implementation 'com.expofp:crowdconnected:4.2.12'` to dependencies
and `maven { url "https://maven2.crowdconnected.net/" }`
to repositories.
I did that, but when I am trying to build it it says:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.crowdconnected.android.core:android-core:1.3.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/crowdconnected/android/core/android-core/1.3.6/android-core-1.3.6.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/core/android-core/1.3.6/android-core-1.3.6.pom
       - file:/Users/arystankaliakparov/code/amego/mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/net/crowdconnected/android/core/android-core/1.3.6/android-core-1.3.6.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/core/android-core/1.3.6/android-core-1.3.6.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/net/crowdconnected/android/core/android-core/1.3.6/android-core-1.3.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-expofp > com.expofp:crowdconnected:4.2.12
   > Could not find net.crowdconnected.android.ips:android-ips:1.3.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/crowdconnected/android/ips/android-ips/1.3.6/android-ips-1.3.6.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/ips/android-ips/1.3.6/android-ips-1.3.6.pom
       - file:/Users/arystankaliakparov/code/amego/mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/net/crowdconnected/android/ips/android-ips/1.3.6/android-ips-1.3.6.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/ips/android-ips/1.3.6/android-ips-1.3.6.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/net/crowdconnected/android/ips/android-ips/1.3.6/android-ips-1.3.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-expofp > com.expofp:crowdconnected:4.2.12
   > Could not find net.crowdconnected.android.geo:android-geo:1.3.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/crowdconnected/android/geo/android-geo/1.3.6/android-geo-1.3.6.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/geo/android-geo/1.3.6/android-geo-1.3.6.pom
       - file:/Users/arystankaliakparov/code/amego/mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/net/crowdconnected/android/geo/android-geo/1.3.6/android-geo-1.3.6.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/crowdconnected/android/geo/android-geo/1.3.6/android-geo-1.3.6.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/net/crowdconnected/android/geo/android-geo/1.3.6/android-geo-1.3.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-expofp > com.expofp:crowdconnected:4.2.12
```

so according to logs it's not even looking at https://maven2.crowdconnected.net/, which is weird.

Thanks for any help!

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  // Buildscript is evaluated before everything else so we can't use getExtOrDefault
  def kotlin_version = rootProject.ext.has("kotlinVersion") ? rootProject.ext.get("kotlinVersion") : project.properties["Expofp_kotlinVersion"]

  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1"
    // noinspection DifferentKotlinGradleVersion
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
  return rootProject.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && rootProject.getProperty("newArchEnabled") == "true"
}

apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
  apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
}

def getExtOrDefault(name) {
  return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : project.properties["Expofp_" + name]
}

def getExtOrIntegerDefault(name) {
  return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : (project.properties["Expofp_" + name]).toInteger()
}

def supportsNamespace() {
  def parsed = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION.tokenize('.')
  def major = parsed[0].toInteger()
  def minor = parsed[1].toInteger()

  // Namespace support was added in 7.3.0
  return (major == 7 && minor >= 3) || major >= 8
}

android {
  if (supportsNamespace()) {
    namespace "com.expofp"

    sourceSets {
      main {
        manifest.srcFile "src/main/AndroidManifestNew.xml"
      }
    }
  }

  compileSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("compileSdkVersion")

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("minSdkVersion")
    targetSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("targetSdkVersion")

  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
    }
  }

  lintOptions {
    disable "GradleCompatible"
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

repositories {
  maven { url "https://maven2.crowdconnected.net" }
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven2.crowdconnected.net" }
  }
}

def kotlin_version = getExtOrDefault("kotlinVersion")

dependencies {
  // For < 0.71, this will be from the local maven repo
  // For > 0.71, this will be replaced by `com.facebook.react:react-android:$version` by react gradle plugin
  //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

  implementation 'com.expofp:common:4.2.12'
  implementation 'com.expofp:fplan:4.2.12'

  implementation 'com.expofp:crowdconnected:4.2.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation you provided you need to add another dependencies like

```kotlin
dependencies {
  // all other dependencies
  implementation 'net.crowdconnected.android.core:android-core:1.3.4'
  implementation 'net.crowdconnected.android.ips:android-ips:1.3.4'
  implementation 'net.crowdconnected.android.geo:android-geo:1.3.4'
}
```

to `dependencies` section

Comment: yes I have tried to add them too, but no result

Comment: try to change order to:

repositories {
  
  google()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://maven2.crowdconnected.net" }
}

Comment: also you missed custom maven here
```
buildscript {
  // Buildscript is evaluated before everything else so we can't use getExtOrDefault
  def kotlin_version = rootProject.ext.has("kotlinVersion") ? rootProject.ext.get("kotlinVersion") : project.properties["Expofp_kotlinVersion"]

  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
```